# Validating XML content in XML-schema annotation/appinfo

Tags: c#, xsd

My understanding of XML isn't exactly stunning, but my understanding of content in annotation/appinfo is that you're allowed any well-formed XML, and this is lax validated.  My understanding of lax validation is that elements and attributes will be validated if the relevant schema information can be obtained.

My situation is that I have an XML schema with some content in this section that requires validating.  I have the relevant schemas to validate the content against.

I've taken a totally simple XML schema and added an appinfo element to it, as shown below.  The content of the appinfo is another element declaration, purely for simplicity of not referencing another schema.  The schema I'm trying to validate obviously references something different.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://www.demo.org"
        xmlns="http://www.demo.org"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:appinfo>
        <xsd:element name="Demo">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="A" type="xsd:iteger"/>
                    <xsd:element name="B" type="xsd:integer"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>    
    </xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:element name="Demo">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="A" type="xsd:integer"/>
            <xsd:element name="B" type="xsd:integer"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Note in the appinfo section, I've deliberately mis-spelled "integer" on element A.  If I do this in the main body of the schema, then `XmlSchemaSet.Compile()` will tell me this schema isn't valid.

However, if I use the schema as it's written above, it tells me there is no problem.  In the more complex file I started with, I supplied the external schema to XmlSchemaSet via `XmlSchemaSet.Add()`

I've also tried loading the XML schema from http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd and loading the schema to be validated into an `XmlDocument` and running `XmlDocument.Validate()` but no joy.

I feel like I'm totally missing something totally fundamental after spending hours on this.  Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is not my understanding of `lax`: if you have a declaration

```
<any
  namespace=". . . " 
  processContents="lax">
</any>
```

the content of the corresponding element in the XML being validated will be validated against the schemas corresponding to the namespace(s) specified by `namespace` (if any) - not against any schema it might be using. The declaration for `appInfo` is

```
<xs:element name="appinfo" id="appinfo">
  <xs:complexType mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:any processContents="lax"/>
    </xs:sequence> 
    <xs:attribute name="source" type="xs:anyURI"/> 
    <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/> 
  </xs:complexType> 
 </xs:element>
```

without any `namespace` specification, that corresponds to `namespace="##any"`, that means that there is no validation against any schema.